# Select-String regex for multiple strings

Tags: regex, select-string

I am trying to extract last entry from an curl output to only show me the plugin-name and version.
Unfortunately miserably failing with my command.
Here is the command being used at my end

**curl --silent https://jenkins-updates.cloudbees.com/download/plugins/blueocean-github-pipeline/ --ssl-no-revoke |  findstr href |Select-String -Pattern "[0-9]/([^<]*)<" |Select-Object -last 1 | ForEach-Object { $_.Matches[0].Groups[1].Value }**

Output its giving is
*blueocean-github-pipeline.hpi">1.25.3*

I wish to display only the following
**blueocean-github-pipeline** **1.25.3**

and remove *">* with a tab in between

How should I go about it?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
... | Select-String -Pattern '\d/([^>]*)\.\w+">([^<]*)<' | `
Select-Object -last 1 | `
ForEach-Object { $_.Matches[0].Groups[1].Value + " " + $_.Matches[0].Groups[2].Value }
```

Output:

```
blueocean-github-pipeline 1.25.2
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/QfXViw/1).

*Details*:

- `\d/` - a digit and a `/` char
- `([^>]*)` - Group 1: any zero or more chars other than a `>` char
- `\.` - a dot
- `\w+` - one or more word chars
- `">` - a fixed string
- `([^<]*)` - Group 2: any zero or more chars other than a `<` char
- `<`  - a `<` char.

The final result is the concatenation of Group 1 + space + Group 2.

Comment: Thanks exactly what I was hoping for :-)

Comment: @Rohit You are welcome. This is a common solution when you need to handle disjoint pieces of text to capture them into two groups and later concatenate. There is a way to do it with a replacing approach, but in this case, it is more convenient to use capturing/concatenation.